# Fillna of one column with random float values in range in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have such dataframe, how can I `fillna` with random float values from `-0.5` to `0.5` (bounds included) for `value` column?

```
  city district       date  value
0    a        b   2019/8/1   0.15
1    a        b   2019/9/1   0.12
2    a        b  2019/10/1    NaN
3    c        d   2019/8/1   0.03
4    c        d   2019/9/1  -0.36
5    c        d  2019/10/1    NaN
```

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want replace same value each `NaN`? Or different values?

Comment: Different values for sure :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If want replace each `NaN`s use [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df['value'] = df['value'].mask(df['value'].isna(), np.random.uniform(-0.5, 0.5, size=len(df)))
```

Or [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['value'] = np.where(df['value'].isna(), 
                       np.random.uniform(-0.5, 0.5, size=len(df)), 
                       df['value'])

print (df)
  city district       date     value
0    a        b   2019/8/1  0.150000
1    a        b   2019/9/1  0.120000
2    a        b  2019/10/1  0.227054
3    c        d   2019/8/1  0.030000
4    c        d   2019/9/1 -0.360000
5    c        d  2019/10/1 -0.001102
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment - you're right, I needed to specify the size because else they'll all get filled with the same random number

Comment: Thank you for your help. Does `np.random.uniform(-0.5, 0.5)` include `-0.5` and `0.5`?

Comment: @ahbon - If check [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html) it `includes low, but excludes high`

Comment: Another question, can we set `seed` to fix and reproduce the results?

Comment: @ahbon I think yes, add `np. random. seed(2019)` before solution. Then get always same values if re run solution.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify what you mean by "random". Assuming you mean "uniformly at random", you can use `fill_na`:

```
df.value = df.value.fillna(
    pd.Series(np.random.uniform(-0.5, 0.5, size=len(df)), index=df.index)
)
```

Comment: It seems fillna with one random value?

Answer (score 1):

You can use apply method:

```
def func(val):
    if np.isnan(val):
        return random.uniform(-0.5, 0.5)
    else:
        return val

df['value'] = df['value'].apply(func)
```